# how to avoid querystring null reference problem

Tags: c#

my coding is

```
if (Request.QueryString["uid"].ToString() != "0")
{
   string dummy  =Request.QueryString["uid"].ToString();
   Label1.Text = dummy;
    Response.Redirect("../Profile/Home1.aspx?uid="+ dummy );
}
else
{
    Label1.Text = "none";
    Session["AccountId"] = 0;
}
```

my problem is am using in this coding in home page.. if it is the first page in website querystring creates problem.. if the user starts with login page means it works. now i want to avoid the querystring problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to fix your if condition to check for `null` - otherwise you will get an Exception when trying to call `ToString()` on `null`:

```
if(Request.QueryString["uid"] != null &&  Request.QueryString["uid"].ToString() != "0")
```

But there is a better way to do this - `QueryString` already returns a string:

```
if(Request.QueryString["uid"] != null && Request.QueryString["uid"] != "0")
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for reference.

Request.QueryString[index] returns a string.

The ToString is actually completely redundant, and is causing your problem. (null).toString() results in a null reference exception.

```
    string uid = Request.QueryString["uid"];
    if (uid != "0") {
        Label1.Text = uid;
        Response.Redirect("../Profile/Home1.aspx?uid="+ uid);
    }
    else {
        Label1.Text = "none";
        Session["AccountId"] = 0;
    }
```